# How can I properly structure my NodeJS, Express, and MongoDB code?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am new to all three but I do know javascript well. I understand basics of them all but do not understand what the best way to implement the NodeJS server javascript with the express MVC and MongoDB database querys. I want to break up all this into their own files obviously but I am not sure how everything fits into the pre-created project template created by Express. Does anyone have a good solution or resource to share with me? Thank you

Comment: Hi. I have made a meetup in spanish covering CRUD basics in NodeJS, Express & MongoDB. Here is the repo: https://github.com/hermanjunge/herman-mongoose-tutorial

Comment: If you think this could serve your needs, let me know, so I can start the translation of this resource to english. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here is an intro to Node.js & Express that I wrote: http://hectorcorrea.com/blog/introduction-to-node-js

Answer (score 0):

I recently started with node.js, express and mongodb myself and it's true the resources out there are mostly outdated. First of all, express is not an mvc framework. It has no opinion on the structure which you'll find out that it makes it so great. Your question is how to organise the code? It's clearly a personal preference but you can create a model folder where you can put your db queries for specific resources, your lib folder where you can establish a connection to your mongodb instance and call it wherever you need it and use the routes folder for your more specific needs like controllers on a traditional MVC. Another thing is that you have to decide how to interact with mongo. You can either use the native mongodb driver, perhaps with mongoskin as suggested, or mongoose for easier interactions such as defining schemas. Personally i prefer the native but it took me a while to get what it does and how it works. Finally for resources what i can suggest from personal experience and it's still my own opinion, is that the best thing you can do is buy the book Node.js in Action which was what made me realize what node.js is all about and how to use it. Hope it helps...